# Free heightmap dataset for Kraków, Poland?

Tags: data, poland

Is there a freely available (governmental?) heightmap dataset for Kraków city (in Poland) with horizontal grid ~5m (or better) and vertical resolution ~ +/- 0.1m? Ideally, it would *include* building heights (i.e. not "ground level").

If you don't know one, at least do you know of some good open forum where I could ask such a question with some hope of getting an answer?

*Sorry if that question doesn't use proper terms and/or is too unclear, or otherwise totally ridiculous; I'm totally unexperienced in GIS.*

Comment: In response to your second question, the Open Data stackexchange (http://opendata.stackexchange.com/) may be able to provide you with answers.